# Jython import or reload dynamically

Tags: python, jython

I have to code something in Jython, for CCPS (programm using jython as scripting interface). However Jython does not update the submodules if I change them in an editor, unless I restart the programm (startup time is prohibitive). SO testing and adjusting is relatively slow.

I have googled and found a post indicating, that one should import or reload the submodules. The basic outline thus is:

```
def loader(module, part=None):
    if not module in sys.modules :
        if part == None:
            exec("import "+module)
        else:
            exec("from %s import %s" % (module, part))                
    else :
        exec("reload "+module)
```

however I have an issue with this, the module is loaded locally, meaning i can access the module within the `loader()` function, but not in my main code.

**Two questions:**

What is the right way to test something with submodules in Jython without restarting Jython after each submodule change?
Is there a way to generate globals dynamically so I can import into the global namespace?

(e.g. `exec("global %(mod)s = %(mod)s" % ({'mod':module}))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about just unloading all modules so they are reloaded on the next import:

```
import sys
sys.modules.clear()
```

Comment: I failed to find it, and here is an even more detailed explanation: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/81731-reloading-all-modules/. Also for some reason no one else could help me with this for a year...

Comment: I've tried with Jython 2.5.2 and it doesn't work, `sys.modules.clear()` doesn't complain, but classes aren't reloaded.  :-(